# ImpersonateLoggedOnUser and starting a new process that uses ocx fails

Tags: c++, winapi, com, ocx

I write a c++ windows application (A), that uses LogonUser, LoadUserProfile and ImpersonateLoggedOnUser to gain the rights of another user (Y).
Meaning the A starts using the user that is logged on on the workstation (X). If the user wants to elevate his rights he can just press a button and logon as another user without having to log himself out of windows and back in.

The situation now is (according to the return values of the functions): LogonUser works, LoadUserProfile works and ImpersonateLoggedOnUser works as well.

After the impersonation I start another process. This process is an application (B) that needs an OCX control. 
This fails and the application tells me that the .oxc file is not properly installed.

The thing is, if I start B directly as the user that is logged on to the machine (X), it works.
If I start B directly as the user (Y) to which I want to elevate my rights using A, it works.

If I am logged in as (X) and choose "run as" (Y) in the explorer, it works!

Do you know which steps I need to do to do the same as the "run as" dialog from windows?

Comment: Could be the environment vars especially if the com registration is using %CommonProgramFiles%\SomeDirHere\MyLib.OCX for InProc server location. Dump the environment of the spawned process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. 
The following was able to solve the issue for me:
I start the desired process using **CreateProcessWithLogonW()**. 
To get that function working properly I have to **RevertToSelf()** before I call it and do the impersonation again afterwards.

So the sequence is now:

```
LogonUser()
LoadUserProfile()
ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()
// work with the app
RevertToSelf()
CreateProcessWithLogonW()
// do the impersonation stuff again
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but looks like impersonation is not enough - impersonation relates only to process (A), instead try CreateProcess with ProcessAttributes/ThreadAttributes  explicitly set to impersonated user from windows' ACL

Comment: thanks for your hint that the impersonation relates only to (A)
Now I tried to use CreateProcessWithLogonW() which MSDN tells me is to be prefered to CreateProcessAsUser().
Now the sequence is:
LogonAsUser()
LoadUserProfile()
ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()
CreateProcessWithLogonW()

where CreateProcessWithLogonW() fails with ErrorCode 5 (Access denied)
Any ideas where to go from here?

Comment: Try sysinternal utils (FileMon or RegMon) to explicitly see what exactly was asked before rejecting by "Access denied". Also per msdn: "By default, CreateProcessWithLogonW does not load the specified user profile into the HKEY_USERS registry key. This means that access to information in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry key may not produce results that are consistent with a normal interactive logon". Note that OCX intensively uses registry.

Comment: @Dewfy: thanks for the hint. Especially the tools you mentioned will be useful for me in future as well!

Access denied is resolved by calling RevertToSelf() before calling CreateProcessWithLogonW()